# Screen Freeze after installing firmware-linux-nonfree

Tags: debian, firmware, amd-graphics, radeon, powerpc

I installed `firmware-linux-nonfree` on my 15" Powerbook G4 running Debian 8.7.

The idea was to enable hardware acceleration to improve the graphics performance. I added the

```
append="radeon.agpmode=-1
```

line to the `yaboot` configuration file to prevent freezes as per the FAQ instructions but still I get random freezes in the first couple of minutes until I purge the `firmware-linux-nonfree` again.

I have a Mobility Radeon 9600 PRO Turbo graphics card. Has anyone got this to work and if so how?

Comment: I believe this could be the same problem that causes freezing in Ubuntu Mate 16.04 ppc and Lubuntu 16.04 ppc. Has anyone managed to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `radeon.agpmode=-1` as a boot parameter solved the problem. I found this advice on the Ubuntu Powerpc FAQs page.